# R - Translate matrix like object (more than 3 values) into RGB system

Tags: r, rgb

I have the following data:

```
head(spca,3)
        Axis 1       Axis 2     Axis 3      Axis 4    Axis 5
P2    0.41785706 -2.215135138  1.1873094 -1.90061886  1.42734543
P92  -3.10662325  2.062759336  2.9738782  0.34503630 -2.4026353
P144 -4.68879566  2.090462774  3.7421616  0.03259024  1.046545319

head(coord,3)
    Longitude Latitude
P2   35.13092 32.51011
P92  35.34025 32.55186
P144 35.47386 32.85336
```

I create  colours for the rows using the [colorplot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/adegenet/versions/2.0.1/topics/colorplot) command from the `adegenet` package. The command uses the spca table and translates it into the RGB system.

```
plot(c(34.6,35.9),c(31.2,33.5),cex=.01, ylab="",xlab="")
colorplot(coord, spca1, axes=1:5, transp=TRUE, add=TRUE,cex=2.5)
```

[image: And the plot looks like this.]

But I actually want to plot this on a `ggplot` where colorplot does not work and I need colour gradients that represent the relationship of the rows as described by the 5 axis. So I wonder how I can create the colours like colorplot myself to use it in ggplot's `geom_point`?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of dataset for testing, this might still be possible to answer.

In order to find an answer to these types of question initially try `?colorplot` or `help(colorplot)`. Look under the 'value section', which describes what the function returns for further use. Here we are told the function will return the colours used during the plotting.

```
plot(c(34.6,35.9),c(31.2,33.5),cex=.01, ylab="",xlab="")
colours <- colorplot(coord, spca1, axes=1:5, transp=TRUE, add=TRUE,cex=2.5) 
ggplot(data = coords)+geom_point(aes(x = <column 1 name>, y = <column 1 name>), 
                                 col = colours, size = 2.5)
```

should give you the same (or a similar) answer (change the coordinates in the `aes(...)` argument to match your data, and change the size to your liking).

Comment: In fact, I tried that, but I did not call the plot first. So it did not work. If I call the plot first, like you did, it works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. 
It is possible to 'extract' the code which calculated the colours. This requires a bit of getting used to, but one may call the function without any parameters `colorplot` and it will output the code. From there one may read the code and often with a bit of training one can find the part which calculates what is of interest. 
It can be time consuming though.